# I need some help with this bernoulli's equation that is given in my assignment

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:

$$y′−\frac{6y}{x}=\frac{y^5}{x^{13}}$$

I have tried again and again but my answer is still wrong. Can someone show me the steps to solving this question?

Comment: bro..i am new here so i don't know how to write the steps or how to even use this website. I have tried this question for the past two hours. if you think you can help me. i'll be indebted to you.

Comment: Here's a tour of the website and a MathJax tutorial: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: and if i show you my working would that merit your company your majesty?

Comment: Its related to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322499/solve-the-following-differential-equations/322517#322517

Comment: @loveass2 Is "Bisch" an English word ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Bernoulli equation of the form
$$y^\prime+p(x)y=q(x)y^\beta$$
we use substituation $u=y^{1-\beta}$. So with $\beta=5$ we have $u=y^{1-5}=\dfrac{1}{y^4}$ then $u'=-\dfrac{4y'}{y^5}$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\frac{y^5u^\prime}{4}-6\frac{y}{x}  &=& \frac{1}{x^{13}}y^5\\
-\frac{u^\prime}{4}-6\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{y^4}  &=& \frac{1}{x^{13}}\\
u^\prime+\dfrac{24}{x}u                &=&  -4\frac{1}{x^{13}}\\
x^{24}\left(u^\prime+\dfrac{24}{x}u \right) &=& -4 x^{24}\frac{1}{x^{13}}\\
x^{24}u'+24ux^{23}&=& -4 x^{11}\\
(x^{24}u)'&=& -4 x^{11}\\
x^{24}u&=& -\dfrac13 x^{12}+C\\
\frac{1}{y^4}   &=& -\frac{1}{3x^{12}}+\frac{C}{x^{24}}                               
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: how do i reprsent this simply as a function of y. like only y is on l.h.s with no power or anything?

Comment: $$y=\pm\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{3x^{24}}{C-x^{12}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $y=\frac{x^6}z$ which makes the equation to become
$$x^{11}+z' z^3=0$$ which is quite simple.